# A world where lichens take the niche of plants?

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, xenobiology, flora, fungi

On this hypothetical world the niche that would be occupied by plants is instead occupied by fungi living in symbiosis with cyanobacteria and/or algae.

For example, the tissues of the tree analogues are actually mycelium, highly specialized in a manner similar to the zooids of siphonophores.

How plausible is this scenario? What other adaptations would the lichen be expected to have?

Answer (score 0):

A good jumping off point might be [Lichens of the Pacific Northwest - Oregon USA](http://www.theenchantedgallery.com/lichen.html) Lichens aren't just flat and scaly, but can be stranded, tubule, or coral looking. I think your idea is plausible, so far as you've explained it. I don't know if they'd technically be actual lichens, but they may be very lichen like. The adaptations would depend on their environment. Global temps, type of star, moisture levels, etcetera...